# How to make dotted border of a cell in iText 5.1.0 with adobe reader compatibile?

Tags: java, itext

I am using code below  to make dotted border cell in `itext 5.1.0`

Class for dotted cell event

```
public class DottedCell implements PdfCellEvent {

public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell,Rectangle position,PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
    PdfContentByte cb=canvas[PdfPTable.LineCanvas];
    cb.beginText();
    cb.setLineDash(1.0f,1.0f,2);
    cb.stroke();
    cb.endText();
}
}
```

Class which is i used to run

```
    Class PdfExample {
  
    public static final String dest="";//address of destination
    public static PdfContentbyte=cb;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    Document document new Document(new Rectangle(792f,634f));
    PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(dest));
    ByteArrayOutputstream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.open();
        PdfPTable table =new PdfPTable();
        PdfPCell cell=new PdfPCell();
        cell.setPhrase("hello pdf");
        DottedCell dottedCell=new DottedCell();
        cell.setEvent(dottedCell);
        table.addCell(cell);
        document.add(table);
    }
}
```

In this example dotted border cell is shown perfect in browser and Document Viewer.

But when opens in adobe reader is not show correctly.
it shows like:-
//result of this code
[image]

Comment: Seems like you are confusing "dotted" with "dashed". Please clarify: what do you mean when you write "dotted"? Your code tells me that you mean "dashed". "Dashed" is also what your screen shot shows (and what other PDF viewers should show). Please clarify what's wrong with the dashed line in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Problem is that in adobe reader it shows dashed but in improper way like my screen shot. But i want like this:-                                                                                                                       hellopdf                                                                                                           ----------                                                                                                                          with fixed spacing between dashes and fixed length of a dash.

Comment: A dash pattern is a dash pattern is a dash pattern. No matter how you create it, the viewer should visualize it accordingly. If the viewer doesn't show it correctly, why blame the tool that created the dash pattern? You are created a dash with *length* `1` and *gap* `1`. It is kind of weird that you define a *phase* with length `2`. That means that you want your first dash to have a length of `-1` (why? maybe there's a reason, but the reason could be that you don't understand your own code).

Comment: i am not blame the tool which created the dash pattern. but i wants to know the reason why all other viewers show properly that i want . But In adobe it not shows proper.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Adobe Reader. We have a whole list of PDFs that conform with ISO-32000-1, but that don't show correctly in Adobe Reader. It could be a zoom factor problem, but the main question I have for you is: **Why do you define a phase of 2, when the length of the dash and the gap are only 1?** This should be equivalent to a *phase* of 0, shouldn't it?